# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS: NTLDR missing

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

Let me start by stating I'm not a computer buff so I'd greatly appreciate layman's language when you start pouring answers to my questions (!...)
Also, I've been using Ubuntu in various versions for over 8 years and I'm very happy with it (I was still using 14.04 LTS until 2 days ago).

So, two days ago I freshly installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS from USB (with full SDD checking and cleaning): so far so good. I worked for a day and a half till last night when I switched the machine off. This morning when powering up I got the "NTLDR is missing" message and obviously didn't get the PC to work.

I've checked the boot order and it's correct. I've tried changing boot from UEFI to Legacy+UEFI and back but with no results.

- If everything (restarting the PC) went smoothly after installation what might have happened now?
- And what should I try next?

I only use Ubuntu, so this is not a dual-boot machine.

Comment: On a different computer, prepare a USB stick with a Live version of Ubuntu. Boot the computer from it and see if the partitions (EFI and Ubuntu) can be seen. If so, you need something like [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). If not, this may point to a hardware problem.

Comment: Thanks, Jos, for your input. Unfortunately it was a hardware problem!

Answer (score 0):

If you already checked the boot device in bios and is your ssd then:

Verify if you have any usb device attached to the computer(camera,usb stick, etc)

If you do the computer might try to boot from them and they might no be bootable so remove them.

Also if you have card reader with a card inside your computer may try to boot form it, remove that also.

The last scenario will be that you ssd might be broken or have hardware issues, you can try to test this by using a new hdd and install ubuntu again if it boots then you ssd is broken.

If you still have warranty for it, you should ask them for a new one.

Hope that my answer is helpful to you

Comment: Thanks, itwolfpower, for your input. Unfortunately it was a hardware problem!